# ¿Reciben algún nombre las palabras cuyas entradas solo aparecen como parte de una locución?

Tags: gramática, solicitud-de-término, dle, locuciones, acepciones

Acabo de ver en Twitter:

> ¡Abrimos un hilo colaborativo! Queremos recopilar todas aquellas palabras que no se valen por sí mismas y solo tienen un hueco compartido en el DLE en el seno de una locución. ¿Nos ayudáis a localizar #PalabrasConvivientes?
>   ¡Comparte y participa! ¡Las publicaremos a barrisco!
>
> <sub>Ensalada de Palabras @EnsaladaPalabra, [Twitter 20 mayo 2020](https://twitter.com/EnsaladaPalabra/status/1263013491549573120)</sub>

El tuit incluye una imagen de la entrada en el DLE de *barrisco*

> [**barrisco**](https://dle.rae.es/barrisco)
>   *Del dialect. barriscar 'dar a bulto y sin peso cosas vendibles', y este de barrer.*
>
> ***a barrisco***
>   Tb. abarrisco, p. us.
>
> 1. loc. adv. En conjunto o sin distinción.

Y luego otra gente ha ido sugiriendo entradas del tipo:

- a la virulé
- rechupete
- oxte
- quisqui
- troche

Y muchas más.

Además de lo interesante del juego, me pregunto: ¿reciben algún nombre estas entradas del diccionario que no tienen significado por sí solas (por tanto acepción), sino solamente como parte de una locución?

Comment: Interesante pregunta. En el texto mencionas un _hashtag_, indicando que se podrían llamar "palabras convivientes". ¿Esta expresión la consideras como una posible respuesta?

Comment: @Charlie en parte... pero le falta la parte de que son incapaces de vivir solas :D

Comment: Supongo que tampoco funcione la palabra Siameses

Comment: Posiblemente palabra a remolque

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Palabras parásitas?

(en cuanto a que cabalga sobre otras)

O, quizás, les podría caber

> palabras polizontes